# redirect olddomain.com all urls that contains question mark

Tags: redirect

How do you redirect all urls on `olddomain.com` that contain question mark to `newdomain.com`'s homepage?
I have an old domain `olddomain.com` and a new domain `newdomain.com`.
The `olddomain.com` has some urls like :

`http://www.olddomain.com/?mode=grp&gid=1140557`
`http://www.olddomain.com/?pid=90063340`

I want to redirect all old domain urls to `http://www.newdomain.com/%E5%85%A8%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%84%E5%AE%89%E3%81%84%E9%80%9A%E8%B2%A9/` 
How to do that in htaccess?

I have try some code, but I can't make it work.

Now I use the code:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

redirect 301 / `https://www.newdomain.com/%E5%85%A8%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%84%E5%AE%89%E3%81%84%E9%80%9A%E8%B2%A9/`
```

The home page `http://www.olddomain.com/` can redirect to `https://www.newdomain.com/%E5%85%A8%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%84%E5%AE%89%E3%81%84%E9%80%9A%E8%B2%A9/`

But all other redirect urls is wrong. Like this:

`http://www.olddomain.com/?mode=grp&gid=1140557`  redirect to `https://www.newdomain.com/%E5%85%A8%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%84%E5%AE%89%E3%81%84%E9%80%9A%E8%B2%A9/?mode=grp&gid=1140557`

`http://www.olddomain.com/?pid=90063340`  redirect to `https://www.newdomain.com/%E5%85%A8%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%84%E5%AE%89%E3%81%84%E9%80%9A%E8%B2%A9/?pid=90063340`

Comment: please add the code you have tried to your post

Comment: Thank you, I have add my code,but I think it is not right.